# A question about understanding the part of limit product approximation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

If $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x) = \infty$ and $0 < c < g(x)$ for all x then $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(x)*g(x)) \geq \lim_{x\rightarrow a}(f(x)*c) = \infty *c = \infty$

My question is can this also work the other way around, so if $ g(x) < c < 0$

If it does, does anything in the procedure change (maybe $\infty$ becomes $-\infty$ or not)

Comment: Yes and yes – just apply your result to $(-g)$.

Comment: It works that way round, you just have to remember $c \lt 0$ so $c*\infty = \infty$ from the initial proof becomes $c*\infty = -\infty$